# Estoy intentando cargar todos mis logos e imagenes que tengo en una carpeta storage estoy usando laravel 5 lo tengo montado en xampp alguna solucion?

Tags: laravel-5

Resulta que tengo este problema la carpeta storage tengo todas mis imagenes del sistema ya que ahi redirecciono todo segun yo tengo que otorgar permisos lo tengo montado en xampp pero a un no si es problema del codigo o del xampp ya que en el servidor me carga sin problemas pero en el xampp ya no me da este error que puedo hacer.

```
            }
        }
    }

    return $finalRequest;
}

public function saveLogos(Request $request)
{
    if (!file_exists(public_path('storage/logos'))) {
        mkdir(public_path('storage/logos'), 0777);
    }
    $finalRequest = $request;

    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        if ($request->hasFile($key)) {
            $extension = array_last(explode('.', $request->file($key)->getClientOriginalName()));
            $name = array_first(explode('.', $request->file($key)->getClientOriginalName()));
            $filename = time() . '-' . str_slug($name) . '.' . $extension;
            $request->file($key)->move(public_path('storage/logos'), $filename);
            $finalRequest = new Request(array_merge($finalRequest->all(), [$key => $filename]));

        }
    }

    return $finalRequest;
}
```

Comment: "mkdir(): No such file or directory" esto me sale en el error final

Answer (score 0):

El comando mkdir no deberías usarlo ahí. Has probado a crear la carpeta manualmente y ver si tu función sube las imágenes ahí??

Si no, mkdir no es tu solución, puedes probar esto:

```
$path = public_path('/userfiles/3/Galleri/1');

File::makeDirectory(public_path()."/".$path,0777,true)
```

Cambia por tus valores

Comment: Ya lo habia intentado de esa manera que comentas sin embargo no me funciono :(

Comment: Prueba esa modificación que he adjuntado, fijate en la barra y después la ruta

Comment: fijate que me funciono ya toda la funcionalidad esta bien pero sin embargo no me carga las imagenes ahora que están alojadas en la carpeta.